# Find current working revision number in bzr after revert -rN

Tags: version-control, bazaar

How can I tell which revision number I am currently compiling/linking (is there a "canonical" name for this revno?), in a `bzr` repo on which I have performed `bzr revert -rN`?

I remember some time ago finding a python script that obtained this info, but I cannot find it now.

Note:

http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/development/en/user-reference/update-help.html is an old question, and the answer involves the use of `bzr update`.
I am not sure if it worked, and if it works now.
But the script I mention did not involve `update` (if so, it was under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

"bzr log", "bzr revno" or "bzr revision-info" will tell you where your branch is at.

Unlike "bzr update", "bzr revert" only changes the specified files in the working tree to the specified revision. It does not affect history or the metadata for the working tree, and thus there is no way afterwards to find the revision those files came from.

In fact, it's possible to revert different files to different revisions in history.

Comment: So you say the answer to my question is "That is not possible"?
I am 99% sure I found and used a python script for that in the past. I am not currently finding it, though.